# Emptiness in the alpha texture

Tags: transparency

When add shader "Glossy" to the alpha texture then emptiness is reflected too. How to make that "Glossy" and other shaders don't affect what should remain invisible?
[image]

Comment: Mix a Diffuse with Glossy first, then mix it with Transapent.

Comment: It works! Thank you so much for your help!